# User create/signin test failing all of a sudden, but works perfectly in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

A couple tests I have are failing all of a sudden and I'm not sure why. Here are my tests that are failing:

```
Failures:

  1) Users signup success should make a new user
     Failure/Error: response.should render_template('users/show')
       Expected block to return true value.
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:33:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Users sign in/out success should sign a user in and out
     Failure/Error: controller.should be_signed_in
       expected signed_in? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And here are the tests:

```
it "should make a new user" do
        lambda do
          visit signup_path
          fill_in "Name", :with => "Example User"
          fill_in "Email", :with => "user@example.com"
          fill_in "Password", :with => "foobar"
          fill_in "Confirmation", :with => "foobar"
          click_button
          response.should render_template('users/show')
        end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

describe "success" do
      it "should sign a user in and out" do
        user = Factory(:user)
        visit signin_path
        fill_in "Email",    :with => user.email
        fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
        click_button
        controller.should be_signed_in
        click_link "Sign out"
        controller.should_not be_signed_in
      end
    end
```

The thing is it passed before and the only thing I did was change the theme (css) of my app. I double checked it in production and it works perfectly. A user does get signedin/out and it does get created. Only the test is failing. Why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some uniqueness constraint on the users table?  Since you aren't using a factory there you might be trying to create a user already in your DB

Comment: I do have a uniqueness constraint but I just checked my DB and it is blank, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What happens when you run the app locally and try the sign in?